# Error connection Databricks to the snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am connection the databricks to the snowflake and send the databrick table to the snowflake.
the connection string and write to the snowflake logics is as:

```
options = {
    "sfUrl": "jdbc:snowflake://xxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfUser": "xxxx",
    "sfPassword": "xxxx",
    "sfDatabase": "DEMOGRAPHICS",
    "sfSchema": "FIRST1",
    "sfWarehouse": "COMPUTE_WH",
}


spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/databricks-datasets/adult/adult.data").write.format("snowflake").options(**options).mode("append").option("dbtable", "table01").save()
```

when I run the above cell it gives the error as:

*Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception.*

*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1980.save.*

NOTE: I am using databricks community edition

Comment: I would try to debug this by splitting up your final line into multiple steps (read, load, etc) and then you can see which part is actually throwing the error - or generating an output that the next step can’t handle